# Node js does not parse the csv file using fast-csv library

Tags: node.js, csv, parsing

I'm using the [fast-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv) node library to parse a csv-file named myFile.csv. The code looks like this:

```
var csv = require("fast-csv");
var fs = require("fs");
var stream = fs.createReadStream('myFile.csv');
                csv
                    .fromStream(stream, {headers : true})
                    .on("data", function(data){
                         console.log("Start of parsing...");
                         console.log(data);
                    })
                    .on("end", function(data){
                         console.log(data);
                         console.log("End of parsing");
                    })
```

When I run it, I see the following two lines in node console:

```
1
End of parsing
```

It doesn't print "Start of parsing..." or any data from the csv file. What could be the reason for that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reinstall fast-csv module by using the following command:

```
npm install fast-csv --save
```

Comment: The solution is not reinstall `fast-csv`, the solution is to use a version which accepts that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `csv` into a variable and then use `stream.pipe()` with it. Like this:

```
var csvStream = csv
                .fromStream(stream, {headers : true})
                .on("data", function(data) {
                    console.log("Start of parsing...");
                    console.log(data);
                })
                .on("end", function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log("End of parsing");
                });

stream.pipe(csvStream);
```

Comment: Your suggestion is another way of writing the same code. I had some other problem with my code. I was running the 0.2.0 version of the fast-csv module. I updated it to the latest version 2.1.0 and now my old code as well as the one you suggested work perfectly fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Verify the types array in your `tsconfig.json`: Confirm that the types array in your `tsconfig.json` file includes the csv-parser entry. Double-check the spelling and casing to ensure it matches the package name exactly. Here's an example of how the updated types array should look:
TypeScript:

```json
"types": [
  "node",
  "webpack-env",
  "fast-csv"
]
```